# trouble with oracle query using a case statement

Tags: oracle, case

I have a materialized view table that contains information on employees and their access to a system
 the table has an "effective_date" columns and "effective_date_to column. this materialized view gets updated once every evening.

I would like to add an extra column  "current_flag" to this table to show if the current employee has access or not with a "Y" or a "N".
I am thinking of using a "case" statement something like the following :-

```
CASE WHEN  to_date(c.effective_date) < to_date(sysdate) 
and to_date      (effective_date_to) > to_date(sysdate)
THEN  'Y'
   ELSE 'N'            
END) AS current_flag
```

Is this the best way to do it and if so what is the correct syntax as I am struggling to get this to work..

the original materialized view table is below...

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TC.employee_access 

(
EMPL_ID,
EFFECTIVE_DATE,
EFFECTIVE_DATE_TO,
DEPARTMENT,
JOB_DESCRIPTION,
TIME_STAMP,
MODIFIED_BY
)
TABLESPACE TC_TC_DATA
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
NOCACHE
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOPARALLEL
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FORCE
START WITH TO_DATE('16-Jan-2013','dd-mon-yyyy')
NEXT TRUNC(SYSDATE+1)
WITH PRIMARY KEY
AS 

SELECT C.EMPL_ID AS Empl_Id,
       C.EFFECTIVE_DT AS Effective_Date,
       DECODE (n.effective_dt,
               c.effective_dt, TO_DATE ('01/01/2099', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
               n.effective_dt - 1)
              AS Effective_Date_To,
       C.DFLT_UDT06_ID AS Department,     
       C.DFLT_UDT08_ID AS Job_Description,
       C.TIME_STAMP,
       C.MODIFIED_BY
  FROM empl_history_mv c, empl_history_mv n
 WHERE n.effective_dt =
          (SELECT NVL (MIN (effective_dt), c.effective_dt)
             FROM empl_history_mv
            WHERE empl_id = c.empl_id AND effective_dt > c.effective_dt)
       AND c.empl_id = n.empl_id;
```

Comment: sysdate is of the type Date and you don't have to do to_date(sysdate)

Comment: What error are you getting? Please post the ORA error message.

Comment: It is absolutely useless (not to say senseless) to use `to_date()` on a column that is already a date.

Answer (score 0):

aside from the extra bracket you have, and the erroneous `to_Date()` It looks valid to me.

i.e. you tried this?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW TC.employee_access 
(
EMPL_ID,
EFFECTIVE_DATE,
EFFECTIVE_DATE_TO,
DEPARTMENT,
JOB_DESCRIPTION,
TIME_STAMP,
MODIFIED_BY,
current_flag
)
...
WITH PRIMARY KEY
AS 

SELECT C.EMPL_ID AS Empl_Id,
       C.EFFECTIVE_DT AS Effective_Date,
       DECODE (n.effective_dt,
               c.effective_dt, TO_DATE ('01/01/2099', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
               n.effective_dt - 1)
              AS Effective_Date_To,
       C.DFLT_UDT06_ID AS Department,     
       C.DFLT_UDT08_ID AS Job_Description,
       C.TIME_STAMP,
       C.MODIFIED_BY,
       CASE WHEN c.effective_date < sysdate
                 and effective_date_to > sysdate
       THEN  'Y'
       ELSE 'N'            
       END as current_flag
  FROM empl_history_mv c, empl_history_mv n
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE`-statement needs access to your computed value `effective_date_to`. You can either do this with an additional set of brackets:

```
SELECT empl_id,
       effective_date,
       effective_date_to,
       CASE WHEN effective_date < SYSDATE AND SYSDATE < effective_date_to
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END current_flag
  FROM (
        SELECT c.empl_id
               c.effective_dt as effective_date,
          FROM ...
       );
```

Or you roll out the logic into one query:

```
SELECT c.empl_id, 
       c.effective_dt as effective_date,
       NVL2(n.effective_dt, n.effective_dt - 1, DATE'2099-01-01') AS effective_date_to,
       CASE WHEN c.effective_dt <= sysdate
             AND (sysdate < n.effective_dt OR n.effective_dt IS NULL) 
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS current_flag
  FROM empl_history_mv c
  LEFT JOIN empl_history_mv n 
    ON c.empl_id = n.empl_id
   AND c.effective_dt < n.effective_dt
   AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT * 
         FROM empl_history_mv t
        WHERE c.empl_id = t.empl_id
          AND c.effective_dt < t.effective_dt
          AND t.effective_dt < n.effective_dt
       );
```